# Java: synchronized method exception and write visibility

Tags: java, synchronization

If a synchronized method throws an exception, do member writes made in it prior to that throw become visible to other threads? E.g.

```
class Foo
{
    private int x;

    public synchronized void foo()
    {
        x++;
        // some other code using x that throws RTE for a specific thread
    }
}
```

If an object of Foo is shared between threads t1 and t2, and t1 throws an exception as shown, in that case will the latest value of x be flushed to main memory so that it's visible to t2 when it enters foo for that object?

Comment: I assume you intended your `foo` method to be synchronized?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Oops! Made the change. Thx.

Comment: if maintain a stack where you store info of usage your method then defiantly next time when any other thread going to execute, that can retrieve the info that what happened last time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, changes will still be visible - you're still exiting the synchronized block, releasing the monitor in the process, and the memory model doesn't care how that occurs - just that it *does* occur. It's still an "unlock action on a monitor" in the terms of [JLS section 17.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4), so it synchronizes with the next action on the same monitor.